# Find lines that have specific distance between them in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, parallel-lines, duplication

I have a rather large dataset that contains duplicated lines with an offset of 1m-5m and I want to find an efficient way to solve this problem using QGIS. Is there anyway in QGIS to find the lines that have a specific distance between them?

Comment: My first idea: if the lines are duplicates then length and number of vertices must be pairwise equal. Maybe you can identify the pairs by joining the layer with a copy of itself on fields containing the length and number of vertices, not having the same fid. If the they are not exactly equal they are completely within a buffer of say 10 m around the counterpart.

Comment: if you are familiar with postgis  
pseudo query: 

select a.gid, g1.gid FROM (
SELECT gid, st_offset(-1*st_X(geom), -1*st_y(geom) geom) g from a)) g1 , a WHERE a.gid != g1.gid AND st_equals(g.geom, g1.geom) IS TRUE 
AND st_dwithin(a.geom, g1,geom , 10 ) 

That would return all gid from table which are same when moved to  0,0 and are within 10 units from each other in original coordinates

How to do it in qgis , no idea

Answer (score 2):

Just followed the comment by @simplexio. (by a Virtual Layer).

(1) Go to `Layer | Add Layer | Add/Edit Virtual Layer`

(2) [Import] line dataset (`many_lines` in the following example)

(3) Query: (within 5m)

```
SELECT * FROM many_lines a
CROSS JOIN many_lines b
ON a.id<> b.id AND st_intersects(st_buffer(a.geometry, 5), st_buffer(b.geometry, 5))=1
```

To test various offset (1~5m), please change `5` in the above syntax to other values.

(4) Create a buffer of 5m for the virtual layer to check visually.

[image]

And the attribute table of the Virtual Layer will look like this:

[image]
Please note duplicates like 0-1, 1-0 pair, 0-2, 2-0 pair, ...